# Better Approach for storing data in Angular Application or calling with maxlength to backend

Tags: angular, caching, arraylist, pagination

I am creating an angular6.x application which shows a list of data in form of tables. The data can be of any size(considering that it is a huge set of data coming from Data). Which approach is best suggested to be followed. Do i call all the data and store it in local storage or variable or I call api with pagelimit lets say 100 data and every time user comes to bottom of scroll make another api call.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement data load on scroll (lazy loading). In this way, you can have less time making an API call and you'll show the data only which is needed

Comment: But when we call api multiple times where would all the data be stored

Comment: you can save that in common service or if you want you can implement ngrx see this https://medium.com/@nikhilkapoor17/real-time-example-of-ngrx-angular-2a298098b034